# How to import script from a neighboring folder in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have folders structure like this:

```
folder_a/
   |_______ x1.py 
   |_______ x2.py
   |_______ x3.py 
   |
folder_b/
   |_______ zzz.py
```

In **zzz.py** I use this code below to import scripts from **folder_a**:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../folder_a/')
from x1 import *
```

I think that this is much more slower and not pythonic-like to use this mechanism of import. I created  `__init__.py` inside **folder_a** to make python think that this is a package, but get the error

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

It does not fit into my head how to apply this system of modules and packages in my case. How to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Comment: not shure that this answer my question